# XPath: Select one of the h4 tag from multiple h4 tags

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I am working on a web scraping project. So I inspected my target page and got the following element from *inspect*. Now there are two h4 tags and subsequently two paragraphs below them. I want to extract the paragraph that is under the h4 *Skills* tag. My answer should be - Python, Java, Django. How can I achieve it?

Here is the inspected element:

```
<div class='someclass'>
    <section>
        <h4>Skills</h4>
        <p>Python, Java, Django</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h4>Prerequisites</h4>
        <p>Coding</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath to get the skills string is

```
//h4[text()='Skills']/..//p
```